# Using Java change content of text file

Tags: java, file-io, randomaccessfile

There is a text file like this:

```
abcd 
1234
```

and the code I am using :

```
RandomAccessFile file = null;       
  try {
     file = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Users\\z36137zz\\Desktop\\test.txt", "rw");
     file.writeBytes("edcba\n");
     file.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

And I want to change the first line to "edcba", I used the RandomAccessFile Class, but If I write "edcba", it will cover "1" of the second line.
So what should I do?

Comment: Please append your code so far.

Comment: The first thing you should do, is show us code. From there we can offer assistance.

Comment: You need to read the file, modify the parts you wish, and write the file back out. There's no way to "insert" data without processing the whole file.

Comment: I didn't prepare well,I'm sorry.